# ReferenceError: hasOwner is not defined

Tags: node.js, undefined

Olá, estou trabalhando em uma aplicação node usando principalmente o express e o axios. Estou utilizando controllers e dentro de um desses criei uma função e dentro dessa função, faço uma chamada a outra, porém, esta segunda está sendo dada como não definida.

**ContactController.js**

```
const axios = require('axios').default
const headers = { headers: { apikey: '...' } };

module.exports = class ContactController {

    // Busca um contato por email, se encontrado, retorna seu id
    async hasOwner(email) {
        await axios.get(`https://api.moskitcrm.com/v1/contacts?limit=1&email=${email}`, headers)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.data.results[0]
            })

        return false
    }

    async store(request, response) {

        const { name, notes, email = [], phone = [], deal = 'Nova Oportunidade', product, cpf, ps, language, modality, unit, course, price = 250000 } = request.body

        if (!name) return response.status(400).json({ message: 'Nome não pode ser nulo' })

        const stage = product === 145474 ? 126877 : 128183

        // O erro acontece ao realizar a chamada
        const owner = await hasOwner(email)

        return response.json(owner)
        ...
   }
}
```

**Erro**

```
(node:4344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: hasOwner is not defined
```

Comment: `const owner = await this.hasOwner(email)`?

Comment: @bfavaretto se eu usar this.hasOwner(email), o erro muda para
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwner' of undefined

Comment: Voce tentou declarar a funcao `hasOwner` fora da classe? Porque se voce esta usando dentro da classe, sem o `this`, ela deveria ser declarada fora. Voce deveria usar o `this` como o @bfavaretto mencionou, neste seu caso. A sua funcao `hasOwner` e desse jeito mesmo? Porque parece que ela sempre retorna `false`.

Comment: @CmteCardeal não tentei. Tentei declarando ela na função e chamando com o this, ainda assim não funcionou. Sugere que eu crie em um outro arquivo e a importe nessa classe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido seguindo a ideia do Cmte Cardeal.

Removi a função da classe e a coloquei em um arquivo separado `utils.js` e exportando a função. Dentro da classe fiz o import do arquivo e chamei a função através dele.

**utils.js**

```
const axios = require('axios').default
const headers = { headers: { apikey: '...' } };

module.exports = {

    hasOwner: async function (email) {

        const contact = await (await axios.get(`https://api.moskitcrm.com/v1/contacts?limit=1&email=${email}`, headers)).data.results[0]

        console.log(contact)
        return (contact) ? contact : false
    }

}
```

**ContactController.js**
(O código da store() original foi reduzido para questões de legibilidade apenas)

```
const axios = require('axios').default
const headers = { headers: { apikey: '...' } };
const utils = require('../utils.js');

module.exports = class ContactController {

    async store(request, response) {
        const { email = [] } = request.body

        const owner = await utils.hasOwner(email)

        return response.json({ owner })
    }
}
```